# is there any way to get values of certain column combined into single class?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis

I'm working with two tables with java Spring MVC project.
The result below is SHOP table joined with CUSTOMER table.

```
| SHOP_NAME | SHOP_NUM  | CUSTOMER_NAME | some other columns aside ... |
| --------- | --------- | ------------- | ---------------------------- |
| 'Mr.Jacks'| 1         | 'Bill'        |                              |
| 'Mr.Jacks'| 1         | 'Ryan'        |                              |
| 'Mr.Jacks'| 1         | 'Kate'        |                              |
| 'Mr.Jacks'| 1         | 'Peter'       |                              |
| 'O`sushi' | 2         | 'Jackson'     |                              |
| 'O`sushi' | 2         | 'Park'        |                              |
```

And I want to put these into SearchResult VO, which has

```
private String shopName;
private int shopNo;
private String[] customerNames;
```

and some other variables.

so with the table above, it's gonna be two SearchResult Objects.
one for Mr.Jacks with 4 customer names in it's array
and another one for O`sushi with 2 customers.

is there any way to do this with single query in Oracle using mybatis?
I've been doing this with 2 database access.
one fore selecting shop info and another one for customer column, but I suddenly thought there might be some better way.

Comment: Sure, you can do it with one query. I'm not a MyBatis expert so I can't tell you how to map it there but with plain JDBC you'd need to do a query just like the one you've used to produce the table you've shown. Then iterate over the result set, create a new SearchResultVO for each new SHOP_NUM value and add the customer name from each resultset row to the corresponding SearchResultVO. You might even be able to directly produce a query that returns customer names as an array but I'm not an Oracle expert either so I can't tell you how (and if at all).

Comment: This is a classic N+1 query. You can use a join instead. There's an example here - the key is to code the result map correctly in XML: https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-kotlin-examples/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/example04

Comment: @JeffButler thanks for comment. seems like collection tag is the one. but i'm not doing it with my custom class but String array. Is it gonna still work if I put them in select tag?

Comment: @Thomas this makes sence but isn't it still accessing to database twice?

Comment: No, with a query that uses a join, e.g. `SELECT ... FROM SHOP s JOIN CUSTOMER c ...` would just be a single db access.

Comment: @Thomas yes the table above is the result of join query that you mean. what I asked is how to put them into java Object without duplicating SHOP_NAME and SHOP_NUM columns where multiple CUSTOMER_NAME fields remaining as array in the Object.

Comment: Well, you basically iterate over the resultset representing that table and build the VO you need, i.e. whenever you encounter a new SHOP_NUM you create a new VO and set the name, otherwise you ignore SHOP_NAME and just add the customer in that row to the VO representing the current SHOP_NUM.

Comment: @Thomas that is what i've been doing with 2 database accesses. I'm looking for hint for mybatis code doing it at once.

Comment: Well, it would still be a single query using a join with some additional mapping by MyBatis. As I'm no expert I can't tell you how that mapping would look but maybe this gets you into the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663585/mybatis-3-0-5-nested-collection-mapping-example

Comment: @FlippingFlop to make the mapping to an array work, you would need to convert the customer names to an array in SQL. I think that could be done through a PSQL procedure, but it doesn't seem worth the hassle. It would be much easier to use MyBatis N+1 support as in my example, then simply convert List<String> to String[] with one line of Java code.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I used collection tag but I had to make customer name class cause it didn't do with just String. It's working great anyway.